# Error en R: Los argumentos implican un número diferente de filas

Tags: r

Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
# Se debe instalar el paquete ENMeval y me parece que también 'raster' 'sp' dismo' 'paralell' 'rJava'
# install.packages("ENMeval")
# se llama la librería
library(ENMeval)
# objeto con las coordenandas en csv 3 columnas
pres = read.csv(file.choose())
# ob con las coberturas asciis 
asciis = choose.files()

# selecciono sólo las columnas 2 y 3
occ = pres[,c(2,3)]
# complio los asciis y le digo a R que son rasters
env = stack(asciis)
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Error in data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), ind, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 0

Que en español significa:

> Los argumentos implican un número diferente de filas.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada entiendo que cuando escribiste esto `asciis = choose.files()` en realidad es `asciis = file.choose()`, si es así el problema lo tienes en que `asciis` es simplemente una cadena de caracteres que representa un nombre de archivo, no es un data.frame por lo que no es posible ejecutar el `stack` sobre él. Será que debierá ser asi?

```
asciis = read.csv(file.choose())
env = stack(asciis)
```